# Make functions that imply other functions

Tags: java, syntax, opengl

I'm developing a game that often has repetitious code that I can't simplify.

Example of what I do normally:

```
Square object;
GL11.glPushMatrix();   // Pushes a matrix stack down by one. This allows us to rotate our object freely 
GL11.glTranslated(object.x, object.y, 0); // Move object to its position
object.drawToScreen(); // Draws the object
GL11.glPopMatrix();    // Pushes a matrix stack up by one, prevents the translation from affecting other objects in the scene
```

The above code gets bulky and needs to be repeated often.

What I want to do:

```
Square object;
bumpMatrix()
{ // implies GL11.glPushMatrix();   
GL11.glTranslated(object.x, object.y, 0); // Move object to its position
object.drawToScreen();  // Draws the object
} // implies GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

Is there a way to make this happen? I swear I've seen something like it somewhere before in Java. It would allow me to make a single function and not have to Copy/Paste the same group of code several times, just call that function.

Comment: Refactoring 6 lines of code to -- 6 lines of code ... What you are looking for is called a "Closure" currently only available in dynamic languages like Groovy.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Closures are not only a thing of dynamic languages. Java has had a kind of closure in the form of inner classes for a very long time, but with the Java8 release it gained proper lambdas (anonymous functions) as well. Lambdas allow for something like `bumpMatrix(() -> { oneThing(); anotherThing(); })`, but, as the excellent answers here show, this problem can be solved without lambdas just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to the RAII idiom in C++, where you put resource management code in the constructor & destructor of a class. Since Java doesn't have destructors, if you're targeting Java 7 or later you could instead (ab)use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and an [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) (untested):

```
class GLCoordGuard implements AutoCloseable {
    protected GL _gl;

    public Manager(GL gl) {
        _gl = gl;
        gl.glPushMatrix();
    }

    public void close() {
        _gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
}

...
    Square object;
    try (GLCoordGuard guard = new GLCoordGuard(GL11)) {
        GL11.glTranslated(object.x, object.y, 0); // Move object to its position
        object.drawToScreen(); // Draws the object
    }
```

The syntax in the question resembles Ruby's blocks, which get packaged in a [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Proc.html) object and passed to a function, which can invoke it whenever it likes. You can do something similar in Java by passing a lambda (which require Java 8) to another function (untested):

```
public void bumpMatrix(Function<Void,Void> glOps) {
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    glOps.apply(null);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
...
    Square object;
    bumpMatrix((Void unused) -> {
        GL11.glTranslated(object.x, object.y, 0); // Move object to its position
        object.drawToScreen(); // Draws the object
    });
```

Comment: I just realised the lambda needs to return null as well. But you could use Runnable instead of Function<Void, Void>, that accepts no arguments and returns void.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a rather generic answer that I feel is only suited to more complex use cases due to the excessive boiler plate required. You can perfectly simulate a functional paradigms in Java (they've done so in Scala) and use for example the decorator pattern to solve your problem. The general approach is to define an abstract class or an interface with a single method that then can be overwritten by an anonymous inner class.

Simple example for your use case:

```
public class SimpleDecorator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PrintingDecorator() {
            protected void execute() {
                System.out.println("Calling my first function");
            }
        }.apply();
        new PrintingDecorator() {
            protected void execute() {
                System.out.println("Calling my second function");
            }
        }.apply();
    }
}

abstract class PrintingDecorator {
    public void apply(){
        System.out.println("Doing this action before");
        execute();
        System.out.println("Doing this action after");
    }
    protected abstract void execute();
}
```

Running this prints:

> ```
> Doing this action before
> Calling my first function
> Doing this action after
> Doing this action before
> Calling my second function
> Doing this action after
> ```

Now you could go significantly farther and actually just define functions and such and base your decorator on that. So for the unnecessarily complex example:

```
public class FunctionalDecorator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function1<Function0<Void>, Function0<Void>> printDecorator = new Function1<Function0<Void>, Function0<Void>>() {
            public Function0<Void> apply(final Function0<Void> arg1) {
                Function0<Void> resultFunc = new Function0<Void>() {
                    public Void apply() {
                        System.out.println("Doing this action before");
                        arg1.apply();
                        System.out.println("Doing this action after");
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                return resultFunc;
            }
        };

        printDecorator.apply(
            new Function0<Void>() {
                public Void apply() {
                    System.out.println("Calling my first function");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        ).apply();

        //Slightly more complex example (with taking arguments and returning values)
        Function1<Function1<String, String>, Function1<String, String>> addTextDecorator = new Function1<Function1<String,String>, Function1<String,String>>() {
            public Function1<String, String> apply(final Function1<String, String> funcArg) {
                Function1<String, String> resultFunc = new Function1<String, String>() {
                    public String apply(String arg1) {
                        return "Before string\t" + funcArg.apply(arg1) + "\tAfter string";
                    }

                };
                return resultFunc;
            }
        };

        Function1<String, String> echo = new Function1<String, String>() {
            public String apply(String arg1) {
                return arg1;
            }
        };

        Function1<String, String> decoratedEcho = addTextDecorator.apply(echo);

        System.out.println(decoratedEcho.apply("Echo!"));
    }

}

interface Function0<ReturnType> {
    public ReturnType apply();
}

interface Function1<ArgType1, ReturnType>{
    public ReturnType apply(ArgType1 arg1);
}

abstract class Decorator implements Function0<Void>{
    private Function0<Void> func;
    public Decorator(Function0<Void> func){
        this.func = func;
    }
    public Void apply() {
        beforeAction();
        Void result = func.apply();
        afterAction();
        return result;
    }
    protected abstract void beforeAction();
    protected abstract void afterAction();
}

class PrintDecorator extends Decorator {
    public PrintDecorator(Function0<Void> func) {
        super(func);
    }
    protected void beforeAction() {
        System.out.println("Doing this action before");
    }
    protected void afterAction() {
        System.out.println("Doing this action after");
    }
}
```

Running this prints:

> ```
> Doing this action before
> Calling my first function
> Doing this action after
> Before string Echo!   After string
> ```